# If I haven't completed Mass Effect 2 can I still import my saved game to Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've been working my way through ME2 with the goal of finishing it before ME3 came out.  I've now failed that goal due to life, work, and an EVE Online addiction.  Unfortunately, right now I'm like a child on Christmas and I really, really, really want to play with my new toy (ME3).  If I just can't seem to hold off on starting ME3, can I still import my character from my unfinished ME2 game into ME3?  If so, will my ME2 character level transfer over?  Will I get some, if any, bonuses from transferring over my unfinished ME2 character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can only import ME2 characters once they have completed the game. It should be fairly easy to blast through ME2 though, since most of the content is optional, if you don't mind taking some losses on the suicide mission. Be warned, though, if you don't manage to preserve at least 2 companions Shepard will die, precluding importing.

Your level and perks will carry over into ME3, though the highest level in ME2 is only halfway towards the highest level in ME3 (30 and 60, respectively). You may wish to reset your perks at the Normandy, to be able to customize your character properly from the start. Some ship upgrades also carry over.

Comment: Note that at least two squad members do have to live through to the end of the game, or Shepard himself will die.  You can't import a corpse.

Comment: @Shinrai, good point, I'll add it to my answer, thanks!

Comment: Why can't you import a corpse?  They rebuilt Shepard once before!  In all seriousness, I guess this means that I'm going to give up on scouring every planet for minerals and assignments, and instead I'm just going to hit up the Reaper IFF mission tonight and hopefully finish up ME2 tonight.

Comment: Good luck, try and at least get the loyalty of an officer-type fellow (Miranda, Jacob, Garrus) and a tech type, such as Tali or Legion. Garrus joins your squad in ME3, so it'd be in your best interests to keep him alive, and since you need an officer either way, why not?

Comment: What about if it's the second time your playing through Mass effect 2 and you don't finish completely? Can you still pull through your character and choices?

Comment: @Ranga, no, you can only use a save that has been made after the Collector Base in the current playthrough. You should be able to import the first playthrough save, though.